# Zend Database Adapter - Uncaught Exception - Stack Trace Reveals Username and Password

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I am using `Zend_Db_Adapter`, specifically `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract`. I would imagine that this issue extends to other adapters as well. When a `PDOException` is thrown, it is 'uncaught', and in many instances, the stack trace reveals the username and password.

I have verified that the following PDO exceptions all show the credentials in the stack trace:

- SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host *...snip...*
- SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet'
- SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections
- SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user *...snip...* (using password: YES)

My production sites don't show stack traces when there are errors, and I still want to see stack traces for these errors on my development environments, I just don't want the usernames and passwords to be displayed in the clear.

Comment: [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Comment: I have two upvotes and two downvotes. I wish it was required to leave a comment with a downvote. I would really like to know why it was downvoted.

Comment: not sure...downvotes didn't come from me.  Maybe be a little more clear and concise as to what you're looking for?  Don't really see antyhing worthy of a downvote

Comment: You should be using try/catch to suppress this error but even so I still believe that no error message should reveal passwords out in the open. This issue should be taken to the PDO team, please vote here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this by not solving it...  Let me explain:

There's currently no way to disable stack traces from uncaught exceptions.  PHP doesn't let you do that.

So, rather than try to disable it, I'd simply not let an exception go uncaught...  I'd install an [exception handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) which would then **log** the back-trace information.  I wouldn't display it on the screen.  I wouldn't check which environment it's in.  I wouldn't check request information.  I would just log it to a file, and display a generic 500 server error page.

Now, in your handler, you can selectively show call information, so you can choose whether or not to log argument info:

```
set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
    $log = array(
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'trace' => array(),
    );
    foreach ($exception->getTrace() as $item) {
        $trace = isset($item['class']) ? $item['class'] . $item['type'] : '';
        $trace .= $item['function'] . '()';
        $log['trace'][] = $trace;
    }
    save_to_log($log);
});
```

But I take an uncaught exception as a sign of a bug in your application.  You should find them and fix them.  If you get them enough that you're worried about presenting the arguments in the page, then you really need to fix the fact that there are uncaught exceptions in the first place...

**Edit** Here's a demonstration of what happens:

```
class Foo {
    public function doSomething($user, $password) {
        throw new Exception('Something Went Wrong!');
    }
}

$f = new Foo();

$f->doSomething('user', 'passw');
```

[on CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MxH9Ls) results in:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Something Went Wrong!' in /code/MxH9Ls:4
Stack trace:
#0 /code/MxH9Ls(10): Foo-&gt;doSomething('user', 'passw')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/code/MxH9Ls</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

But, with the exception handler (modified to print instead of log):

```
set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
    $log = array(
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'trace' => array(),
    );
    foreach ($exception->getTrace() as $item) {
        $trace = isset($item['class']) ? $item['class'] . $item['type'] : '';
        $trace .= $item['function'] . '()';
        $log['trace'][] = $trace;
    }
    echo $log['message'] . "\n";
    foreach ($log['trace'] as $trace) {
        echo " - $trace\n";
    }
});

class Foo {
    public function doSomething($user, $password) {
        throw new Exception('Something Went Wrong!');
    }
}

$f = new Foo();

$f->doSomething('user', 'passw');
```

[On CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zx1tY3) produces:

```
Something Went Wrong!
 - Foo->doSomething()
```

Comment: I am going to give your solution a try, though it might take me a couple of days to get to it. Thanks!

Comment: Some more background information: The first three are errors that happen when my hosting service has database problems. They rarely happen, but even once is too many times when database authentication credentials are revealed as a result.

Comment: @Sonny: still, you should catch those and process accordingly (present a 500 error page, read from cache, etc)...

Comment: I agree. I will be using your answer as a guide to accomplish what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could try, the first and probably the best solution would be to catch the exceptions and pass them to a custom exception class. The class would also take an instance of the adapter something along the lines of:

**Untested Example**

```
class myPDOException extends Exception
{
     public function __construct($message = '', $code = 0, Exception $previous = null, Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $adapter) {
        $config = $adapter->getConfig();
        $message = str_replace(array($config['username'], $config['password']), array('--user--', '--pass--'));
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
     }         
}
```

Another option would be to use the set_exception_handler after checking in your bootstrap if the env is development, then you can do the following;

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
    if ($exception instanceof PDOException) {
        //load your configuration
        //replace the user pass in the message
        //rethrow the exceptio with the updated message
    }
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

The way I handle unforseen exception is to save them to a queue which then emails me all the necessary information and we can fix the cause of the exception.

Hope that helps

Jay